# How to make classroom greenboard effect using CSS3?

Tags: html, css

I want to achieve classroom greenboard effect(just the green colour with chalky powder effect) using css like in the image shown below

[image]

I have found the font which is close to the writing but for the greenboard I tried picking the colour and applied as a background to the div,but it all looks plain and uniform,which is unrealistic.

Can I achieve that whitish-green effect using CSS?I don't want to use image for that.

(I believe its possible because once I saw a person made a full Coke Can using pure CSS)

Comment: Did you tried it first?

Comment: Even if it's possible to get something like that in CSS (and I've never seen it done) it would take an awful lot of code. It's not practical. A lightweight bg image is a much better option here.

Comment: Questions asking for code must **demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved**. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Comment: I don't agree with the close votes. I've seen CSS questions like 'is this possible' closed before, but if you don't know where to look for fancy abuse of properties to achieve certain effects, it's impossible to do the research. See my answer for how this can easily be done with exactly that - abusing some CSS3 properties.

Answer (score 3):

you can use css3 gradient...use the code below..

```
.greenboard {background: #63856a; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  #63856a 1%, #3c5a40 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0px, center center, 100%, color-stop(1%,#63856a), color-stop(100%,#3c5a40)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  #63856a 1%,#3c5a40 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  #63856a 1%,#3c5a40 100%); /* Opera 12+ */
background: -ms-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  #63856a 1%,#3c5a40 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center,  #63856a 1%,#3c5a40 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#63856a', endColorstr='#3c5a40',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */
}
```

it's not perfect like image because the image contain some texture effects...

Answer (score 3):

You can come pretty close by combining an `rgba` semi-transparent white color for the text color, and then using `text-shadow` with a half-opaque white to make a 'glow' that transparently emulates the granularity of the chalk.

[Working sample here](http://jsfiddle.net/Curry/4akWS/1/).

Adding some clever use of transforms and perspective you can also emulate the effect that people rarely write in a consistent size and direction on a whiteboard, and text usually converges from left to right.

[Funkier sample here](http://jsfiddle.net/Curry/4akWS/2/). Or make it a [tad more transparent](http://jsfiddle.net/Curry/4akWS/3/). Play with it  :)

Answer (score 2):

You can probably do that using gradients.

Here are some links to some websites which offer you to customize gradients, and to add as many 'stoppers' as you want.
http://ie.microsoft.com/TEStdrive/Graphics/CSSGradientBackgroundMaker/Default.html
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient